# [Verilog]Why my counter's output delays one more clock?

Tags: counter

My partial program  is as followed, it's a FSM to handle the traffic light,and the register "times" (from 4 to 1) is to compute the time that the traffic light should brighten, But whenever "times" counts to "1", the time of "times=1" is longer than other "times" about one clock.

For example:when times = 4~2,every clock will count ,but when times=1,it will take two clocks
to become times=4.

Could anybody tell me how this problem happened?

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst  )
                if(!rst)
                    begin
                        s1<=state1;
                        A<=3'b0;
                        B<=3'b0;
                        count1<=3'd4;
                        count2<=3'd2;
                        count3<=3'd3;
                        count4<=3'd2;
                        temp<=1'b1;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        if(temp==1)
                            begin
                                temp<=1'b0;
                                case(s1)
                                    state1:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count1;
                                            A<=3'b001;
                                            B<=3'b100;
                                            s1<=state2;
                                        end
                                    state2:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count2;
                                            A<=3'b010;
                                            B<=3'b100;
                                            s1<=state3;             
                                        end
                                    state3:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count3;
                                            A<=3'b100;
                                            B<=3'b001;
                                            s1<=state4;

                                        end
                                    state4:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count4;
                                            A<=3'b100;
                                            B<=3'b010;
                                            s1<=state1;
                                        end
                                    default:
                                        begin
                                            A[0]<=3'b000;
                                            B[0]<=3'b000;
                                        end
                                    endcase
                            end 
                        else
                            begin
                                if(times>1)
                                    times<=times-1;
                                else if(times==1)
                                    begin
                                        temp<=1'b1;//can't count averagely

                                    end
                            end
                    end
```

Comment: Is there more code? or any at all?

Comment: yes,but this site said that my article is almost code although I only post 4 lines of my code

Comment: From the information posted, a solution cannot even be attempted.

Comment: where can I place my code?

Comment: Edit your first post and paste the code. All code needs to be indented by four spaces, otherwise it will not allow you to post.

Comment: You should tag what language this is. It helps people find the questions and it helps with syntax coloring.

Comment: sorry,I will improve it